# Dynamical compilation error in exe-wrapped JAR

Tags: java, jar

I created a Java application (a JAR), which will dynamically compile external Java sources that implement an interface in the JAR. To ease users, I turned the JAR file into an executable following this [solution](https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa), but I encounter an error relating to the loading of JAR:

```
cannot read zip file entry
```

I understand that the JAR has been embedded into the executable, so is there any way I can load it correctly (or self extracting) when dynamically compiling?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the link you've provided the executable (hello.run) is composed by the script (stub.sh) and by the jar (helloworld.jar).

You can extract the JAR part from the executable. Read the executable, skip the first n bytes, where n is the size of the script, and then save the remaining bytes in a tmp file. The tmp file is your jar.

Comment: I think your solution is doable. But to avoid complex in code, I decide to make an installer which will copy the JAR and the executable to a directory, so executable do the command job, and JAR do the compilation job.